# Find the equivalent resistance when wires are joined infinitely

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image: Just a part of the infinite Meshwork of wires]

Consider that this Meshwork is just a part of the infinitely wires woven together in this manner. Every four wires interest to form a square, as can be seen in the diagram. Suppose the resistor of every wire is R. Find the equivalent resistance from moving from one end to the other end of a wire (for example, consider wire BD)

I am not getting any idea to solve this. I just got this problem and liked the question. Therefore, posted it here.

**I request, please give a proper justification and the approach.**

Comment: This is not a "we do your homework for you for free" community. If you have homework or exam related questions, you should at least show some effort and ask about specific concepts rather than posting the problem as given. This will help **you** understand the solution better.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: For recommendations of alternative sites which might be suitable see [my question was closed on phys se - can you recommend me another internet site?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/) You might like to try http://physics.qandaexchange.com.

Comment: http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath668/kmath668.htm